# Erro 500 no servidor- URL inválida

Tags: htaccess, http, lado-do-servidor

Sempre que tendo acessar uma URL que não existe no meu site, aparece este erro

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.

Tem alguma forma de personalizar esta mensagem de erro ou mostrar uma página padrão?

O site está no Wordpress e não tem .htaccess, porém consigo alterar as configurações do Apache diretamente.

Inseri a linha

```
 ErrorDocument 500 /error/erro500.html
```

e apareceu mais um erro:

> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered
>   while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: "*Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.*" - Ou seja, ainda deu mais um erro dentro do seu processo de tratamento de erros. :(

Answer (score 1):

Caso esteja usando Apache como servidor WEB, adicione essa linha no arquivo *.htaccess*:

```
ErrorDocument 500 http://yourwebsite.com/error-500
```

Esse arquivo *.htaccess* deve estar na raíz dos diretório público do site.

O ponto estranho na sua questão é que o erro 500 deveria indicar um erro interno no servidor.

O código correto para página inexistente é o código 400.

Talvez tenha algo mal configurado no servidor ou pode até ser algum comando enviado por scripts como PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode personalisar os erros sim.

```
ErrorDocument 500 "Sorry, our script crashed. Oh dear"
ErrorDocument 500 /cgi-bin/crash-recover
ErrorDocument 500 http://error.example.com/server_error.html
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/not_found.html 
ErrorDocument 401 /subscription/how_to_subscribe.html
```

Referência: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html

Ou caso esteja utilizando servidor nginx:

```
error_page 404 /404.html;
```

No exemplo destes comandos toda vez que houver o disparo do erro, ele irá chamar a mensagem ou página pré-definida. Cuidado para não ocasionar um loop.